# jwplayer width HLS - No playable sources found. What's my mistake?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

JW Player can not play HLS. Here is my HTML code of the page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE> 
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/7XBRYUMN.js'></script>
        <script>jwplayer.key="***";</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my-video"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("my-video").setup({
                file: "http://esioslive6-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/202892/AL_P_ESP1_FR_FRA/playlist.m3u8",
                width: 400,
                height: 240,
                title: "video",
                hlshtml: true,
                type: "hls",
                androidhls: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Player always displays: Error loading player: No playable sources found.
HLS checked online  http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/ 
HLS correctly reproduced.
what's my mistake?

Comment: You are using a free edition licence key. HLS with JW Player requires at least a Premium Edition - costing $299/yr: https://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/

Comment: or you can just use [clappr](https://github.com/clappr) or [video.js](http://videojs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I think your account on jwplayer do not permission for HLS Adaptive Streaming or jwplayer.key does not match with jwplayer js file. I have check with account of demo site and that is play correctly

```
 <!DOCTYPE> 
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/V6NfEzT7.js"></script>
        <script>jwplayer.key="AIzaSyCCd7R6tUAGAwFNlq0hV_C7GWNEZNhzxa4";</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my-video"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("my-video").setup({
                file: "http://esioslive6-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/202892/AL_P_ESP1_FR_FRA/playlist.m3u8",
                width: 400,
                height: 240,
                title: "video",
                hlshtml: true,
                type: "hls",
                androidhls: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```